# Using Twitter-Bootstrap, how do I open a tab at the same time as toggling a modal?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal and in that modal are tabs. The modal is initially hidden, and I have a list of buttons.

Each button is assigned to a tab in the modal. When I click a button, I want the modal to pop up, and then switch to the tab assigned to the button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no "out of the box" solution to this. It takes some jQuery/CSS manipulation.

Essentially, you need to:

1. Create onclick events on each of the buttons
2. Manipulate the CSS to add/show the targeted tab

For the Twitter Bootstrap codebase, you will need to add/remove classes from both the tab link list, and the tab-panes:

```
//remove active class from all links and buttons
$(".tab-pane").removeClass("active");
$(".tab-btn").removeClass("active");

//add active and fade in class to tab link and content pane
$("#home").addClass("active in");
$("#btn_home").addClass("active");
```

I recently added this to a project, so went ahead and wrote a little mockup.

http://coryprice.com/e/twitter-bootstrap/modal-with-tabs/

Comment: Wow - nice work on syncing the tabs with buttons.  Your demo works great.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I found in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589053/how-to-open-specific-tab-of-bootstrap-nav-tabs-on-click-of-a-particuler-link-usi) by @sridhar-r uses the tab('show') method on the target tab to switch tabs like so:

```
function activeTab(tab){
   $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
};
```

So on your click event for the buttons you would just need to make the modal active and specify which tab to open e.g something like this

```
var myClickEvent = function(){
       $('#myModal').modal('show');
       activeTab("mydefaultTab");
};
```