# How to open specific tab of bootstrap nav tabs on click of a particuler link using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to jquery and bootstrap,so please consider my mistakes.I have created a bootstrap modal for login and registration. It contains two nav-tabs called as login and registration.I have two buttons that popup the same Modal window, but display a different tab inside the Modal window. In each tab is a form with a number of inputs. My issue is getting the modal popped up with login tab  opened in the modal when i click on the 'login' button and  registration tab opened when i click on the 'register'  button on my page.

These are 2 links on which the modal opens:

```
<div class="header-login-li" style="background-color:gray;float:left;width:100px;height:60px;">
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#regestration" class="header-register-a" >
<big>
<font color="white" class="header-register-font"><center style="margin-top:20px;">Login <i class="icon-chevron-down" style="font-size:20px"></i></center></font>
</big></a></div>

<div class="header-register-li" style="background-color:green;float:right;margin-right:-15px;width:130px;height:60px;">
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#regestration" class="header-register-a" >
<big>
<font color="white" class="header-register-font"><center style="margin-top:20px;">Register</center></font>
</big></a>
```

Here is my code of tabs and their contents(i am avoiding unnecessary code here):

```
 <div class="tabbable" >
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" ><!--tabs-->
        <li class="active" style="position:absolute;margin-left:0px;" id="logintab">
        <a href="#pane_login" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
        <li style="margin-left:70px;" id="reg_tab" ><a href="#pane_reg" data-toggle="tab">Registration</a></li>

      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content"><!--login tab content-->
         <div id="pane_login" class="tab-pane active">
             <form id="login-form" target="login-signup-iframe" method="post" action="#" name="login-form">

              </form>

        </div><!--/pane_login-->

        <div id="pane_reg" class="tab-pane"><!--registration tab content-->
           <form id="regestration-form" target="login-signup-iframe" method="post" action="#" name="regestration-form">

            </form>
         </div>
        </div><!-- /.tab-content -->
</div><!-- /.tabbable -->
```

I think this can be done through jquery easily.But i dont know exactly how to do it.
So,please can anyone help me to solve my problem.Thank you in advance ?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Applying a selector from the .nav-tabs seems to be working

**HTML** is

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#aaa" data-toggle="tab">AAA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bbb" data-toggle="tab">BBB</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ccc" data-toggle="tab">CCC</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="tabs">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="aaa">...Content...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="bbb">...Content...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="ccc">...Content...</div>
</div>
```

**Script** is

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  activaTab('aaa');
});

function activaTab(tab){
  $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pThn6/80/

Comment: The tab-pane `id` is unnecessary and modifying the `href` feels weird to me. A cleaner solution would be to add an `id` to each tab: then you can change the long selector to something as simple as `$('#' + tab).tab('show');`

Comment: @Skippr If you remove the tab-pane ids, how is each nav-tabs anchor linked to its tab-pane?

Comment: To summarize what's going on here: `.tab('show')` is being called on the `<a>` of the nav-tabs `<li>`

Comment: I tried that solution but it's not working for me. I'm using nav-pills instead of nav-tabs. Here is what I tried http://jsfiddle.net/Lumyc4gs/1/ Can someone please help me to make it work? I'm using angularJs in my application, so may be even simpler solution?

Comment: Never mind, got it to work by combining a few solutions from this thread http://jsfiddle.net/Lumyc4gs/2/

Answer (score 16):

**HTML:**

```
<a href="PageName.php#tabID">link to other page tab</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
window.onload = function(){  

    var url = document.location.toString();
    if (url.match('#')) {
        $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
    }

    //Change hash for page-reload
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').on('shown', function (e) {
        window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
    }); 
}
```

Comment: the id must be between quotations marks :
`$('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');`

Comment: what's wrong with `location.hash` for also reading the hash in the first place?

Comment: @Alnitak yes I don't understand why you would need to update it for a page-reload

Comment: @alias51 that's so that you can bookmark the URL _including the hash_ and automatically have the correct tab opened when you visit it.

Answer (score 11):

You may access through tab Id as well, But that id is unique for same page.
Here is an example for same

```
$('#product_detail').tab('show');
```

In above example `#product_details` is `nav` `tab` id

Comment: OR, if you are using HREF `$('.nav-tabs a[href="#home"]').tab('show')`

Answer (score 7):

Hi Try this one folks!

```js
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
  // save current clicked tab in local storage does not work in Stacksnippets
  // localStorage.setItem('lastActiveTab', $(this).attr('href'));
});
//get last active tab from local storage
var lastTab = "#profile"; // localStorage.getItem('lastActiveTab');
console.log(lastTab + "tab was last active")
if (lastTab) {
  $('[href="' + lastTab + '"]').tab('show');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile</div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">Message</div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">Settings</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for above answer , here is my jQuery code that is working now:

```
      $(".header-login-li").click(function(){
        activaTab('pane_login');                
      });

      $(".header-register-li").click(function(){
        activaTab('pane_reg');
        $("#reg_log_modal_header_text").css()
      });

      function activaTab(tab){
        $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    function updateURL(url_params) {
        if (history.pushState) {
        var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?' + url_params;
        window.history.replaceState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
        }
    }

    function setActiveTab(tab) {
        $('.nav-tabs li').removeClass('active');
        $('.tab-content .tab-pane').removeClass('active');

        $('a[href="#tab-' + tab + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
        $('#tab-' + tab).addClass('active');
    }

    // Set active tab
    $url_params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);


    // Get active tab and remember it
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]')
        .on('click', function() {
        $href = $(this).attr('href')
        $active_tab = $href.replace('#tab-', '');

        $url_params.set('tab', $active_tab);
        updateURL($url_params.toString());
    });

    if ($url_params.has('tab')) {
        $tab = $url_params.get('tab');
        $tab = '#tab-' + $tab;
        $myTab = JSON.stringify($tab);
        $thisTab = $('.nav-tabs a[href=' + $myTab  +']');
        $('.nav-tabs a[href=' + $myTab  +']').tab('show');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a php+css solution I used on my site?
It's simple and no js problems :)

url to page: `<a href="page.php?tab=menu1">link to menu1</a>`

```
<?
$tab = $_GET['tab'];
?>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="<? if ($tab=='menu1' OR $tab=='menu2') 
{
echo "";
} 
else {
echo "active";
}
?>"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Prodotti</a></li>
  <li class="<? if ($tab=='menu1') 
{
echo "active";
} 
?>"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">News</a></li>
  <li class="<? if ($tab=='menu2') 
{
echo "active";
} 
?>"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Gallery</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade <? if ($tab=='menu1' OR $tab=='menu2') 
{
echo "";
} 
else {
echo "in active";
}
?>
">
    <h3>Prodotti</h3>
    <p>Contenuto della pagina, zona prodotti</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade <? if ($tab=='menu1') 
{
echo "in active";
} 
?>">
    <h3>News</h3>
    <p>Qui ci saranno le news.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade <? if ($tab=='menu2') 
{
echo "in active";
} 
?>">
    <h3>Gallery</h3>
    <p>Qui ci sarà la gallery</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may definitely not suggest this. This is a very ill way of doing what he/she has asked.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this snippet, that I've been using for handling this exact case.

It's in plain javascript, making it also suitable in cases like with bootsrap5 without jQuery.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onhashchange=hashTriggerTab;
    window.onload=hashTriggerTab;
    
    function hashTriggerTab(){
        var current_hash=window.location.hash;
        if(current_hash.substring(0,1)=='#')current_hash=current_hash.substring(1);
        if(current_hash!=''){
            var trigger=document.querySelector('.nav-tabs a[href="#'+current_hash+'"]');
            if(trigger)trigger.click();
        }
    }
</script>
```

With that in place, you could link both on the same page, like:

```
<a href='#tabId'>Link Any Tab</a>
```

Or from external page like:

```
<a href='newpage.php#tabId'>Link From External</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understood correctly but here is snippet that I use to **open links from Bootstrap tab menu**:

### HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#foo" data-toggle="tab">Foo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#bar" data-toggle="tab">Bar</a></li>
  <li><a href="baz.html" class="external">Baz</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="foo">Foo</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="bar">Bar</div>
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
$('.nav a:not(".external")').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```