# Link to a bootstrap tab using a specific URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently developing a website using bootstrap, I am using the bootstrap tabs feature to navigate between pages without loading any other html files, but I am also trying to allow URLs to point to certain pages, here is my issue..

I can set the URL to go to the said page using

```
    var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href=#'+url.split('#')[1]+']').tab('show') ;
}
```

But this won't show any of the content which is on the page unless you navigate out of the page and back in, basically if I put text in that tab, it wouldn't show, but if I opened another tab, and then went back in to the page I linked to it would work fine.

Here is a link to what I'm working on: http://xuz.co/dev/takistanmain/

Navigating pages works, but when I use a url like http://xuz.co/dev/takistanmain/#about it will show a blank page as you can see.

Let me know if you need anymore info and I thank you for your assistance!

Comment: possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589053/how-to-open-specific-tab-of-bootstrap-nav-tabs-on-click-of-a-particuler-link-usi

Comment: I suspect this is a timing issue - make sure you do this AFTER bootstrap has set up the tabs. Also, use `document.location.hash` to get the hash portion of the URL more easily with string splitting.