# Error displaying at the tabbed page

Tags: php, jquery, css, codeigniter

Here we have tabbed form http://www.ansonika.com/citytours/admin.html

At the settings part we can change password and email and we are using CodeIgniter server side validation. If we got any error page will reload but first tab will be open.

How we can display that error at the settings tab (Third tab) we are working on?

We though about moving to the first tab that section but when the page is open we need to show booking list.

Comment: Can errors only ever exist on the 3rd tab?

Comment: Yes. Because we have password and email change there. If gives any error after server side verification we need to display that.

Comment: You have to find a way to call specific tab. Something like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589053/how-to-open-specific-tab-of-bootstrap-nav-tabs-on-click-of-a-particuler-link-usi), but with respect of code of plugin you use there in code. Then, you could pass flash data variable that would tell JS  what tab should be open. In other words, you have to work on JS code.