# Bootstrap Tabs - Open particuler tab on a different internal side and jump to anchor by click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi all Regarding [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589053/how-to-open-specific-tab-of-bootstrap-nav-tabs-on-click-of-a-particuler-link-usi) I could solve my problem opening a new page and a particuler tab by using this script

```
window.onload = function(){  

var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href=#' + url.split('#')[1] + ']').tab('show');
}

//Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a[href=#' + url.split('#')[1] + ']').on('shown', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
});
```

}

The link looks like this

```
index.php?content=seminare#wppp
```

I'm using a php include function. In this case I include seminare.php into index.php and open tab WPPP.

The code of the tabs look like this

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs responsive-tabs">
    <li class="active">
       <a data-toggle="tab" href="#monitor"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Monitor</a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a data-toggle="tab" href="#wppp"><i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>WPPP</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="monitor">
        content 1
    </div><!-- tab-group -->

    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="wppp">
        content 2
    </div><!-- tab-group -->
</div>
```

By now I end up on the top of the page without the focus on the open tab.
So I have to scroll down to the tab. How can I manage to jump to the tab area as well as like the normal anchor functionality?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use jQuery to do this easily:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).scrollTop( $("#wppp").offset().top );
});
```

But make sure its visible though.

Comment: The function should work for certain anchor not only for wppp. So I guess I have to replace #wppp with url.split('#')[1] like $(document).scrollTop( $("#" + url.split('#')[1]).offset().top );
Where do I have to place this function and what do you mean with visible?

Comment: Anywhere in the document and what I mean with visible is that you, yourself can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Because the particuler div was hidden it couldn't work.

```
 if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href=#' + url.split('#')[1] + ']').tab('show');
    $('#' + url.split('#')[1]).addClass('active');
}
```

Add class 'active' and it works