# Go to a specific tab through clicking a specific button in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have a modal with two tabs `Login` and `Registration`. I also have two buttons named `Login_Button` and `Registration_Button`.

Now when I clicked on `Login_Button` I want to show the `Login` tabs as well as clicked on `Registration_Button` want to show the `Registration` tabs. But here always open login tab first though I clicked on registration tab.

**Here is my code**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login Button</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Registration Button</button>
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Login_Tab</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Registration_Tab</a></li>
      </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>Login</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Registration</h3>
          <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**I have used bootstrap css and js**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I have already searched [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589053/how-to-open-specific-tab-of-bootstrap-nav-tabs-on-click-of-a-particuler-link-usi?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But not getting the result what I want. Anybody help please ?

Comment: Can you provide the CSS for this page?

Comment: @The KNVB.........Update my post with the css and js

Comment: what do you see in console? any errors? As far as I could see is you have to load jQuery first and then bootstrap

Comment: @Nagaraju....There is no error brother !! I didn't tell anything about error in my post .... I just want something more that I have described in the post. Please read carefully....

Comment: If there is no error, it should work properly.

Comment: @Nagaraju....I want to go to login tab while click loginButton and resgistration tab while clicking in registrationButton. But here always open login tab first though I clicked on registration tab. do you got my point?

Comment: Now I got your point, update your question with the above explanation since its not clear there

Comment: @Nagaraju.....Thanks for the suggestion :)... I have updated my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check my below snippet it is working

```js
$('.modal-toggle').click(function (e) {
    var tab = $(this).data('href');
    $('li > a[href="' + tab + '"]').tab("show");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg modal-toggle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-href="#home">Login Button</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg modal-toggle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-href="#menu1">Registration Button</button>
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" >Login_Tab</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Registration_Tab</a></li>
      </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>Login</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Registration</h3>
          <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need. Capture on click of buttons and you can click on tabs using javascript.

I also changed your modal to have `modal-content` class `modal-header` class

```js
$("#btnlogin").on("click",function(){
    $("li#lilogin>a").click();
    console.log("Clicked Login");
});

$("#btnregis").on("click",function(){
    $("li#liregis>a").click();
    console.log("Clicked registration");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button type="button" id="btnlogin" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login Button</button>
<button type="button" id="btnregis" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Registration Button</button>
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li id="lilogin"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Login_Tab</a></li>
        <li id="liregis"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Registration_Tab</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
          <h3>Login</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Registration</h3>
          <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```