# How to programatically click a href link from bootstrap tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to programatically click a href link from bootstrap tabs.

Here is link to codepen:

[linkToCodePen](https://codepen.io/thorstorm/pen/zYrYEbZ)

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myNavTabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#navtabs1" data-toggle="tab">nav-tab 1</a>
        <li><a href="#navtabs2" data-toggle="tab">nav-tab 2</a>
        <li><a href="#navtabs3" data-toggle="tab">nav-tab 3</a>
    </ul>



    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="navtabs1">nav-tabs content 1</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="navtabs2">nav-tabs content 2</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="navtabs3">nav-tabs content 3</div>
    </div>
```

How to click let's say `second href tab` link within a function from javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [clink method on HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click), so if you add `id`s to the `li > a` of your HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myNavTabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#navtabs1"  id="linktab1" data-toggle="tab">nav-tab 1</a>
    <li><a href="#navtabs2" id="linktab2" data-toggle="tab">nav-tab 2</a>
    <li><a href="#navtabs3"  id="linktab3" data-toggle="tab">nav-tab 3</a>
</ul>



<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="navtabs1">nav-tabs content 1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="navtabs2">nav-tabs content 2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="navtabs3">nav-tabs content 3</div>
</div>

<script>
// You can grab the element and programmatically click on it
document.getElementById('linktabs2').click()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Bootstrap documentation on navigations

[Navs # Via JavaScript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#via-javascript)

```js
jQuery('#linktab2').tab('show')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myNavTabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#navtabs1"  id="linktab1" data-toggle="tab">nav-tab 1</a>
    <li><a href="#navtabs2" id="linktab2" data-toggle="tab">nav-tab 2</a>
    <li><a href="#navtabs3"  id="linktab3" data-toggle="tab">nav-tab 3</a>
</ul>



<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="navtabs1">nav-tabs content 1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="navtabs2">nav-tabs content 2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="navtabs3">nav-tabs content 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to: [How to open specific tab of bootstrap nav tabs on click of a particuler link using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589053/how-to-open-specific-tab-of-bootstrap-nav-tabs-on-click-of-a-particuler-link-usi)

```
$('.nav-tabs a[href="#navtabs2"]').tab('show')
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/p/yvnBZlQljl)

Also, you seem to be using Bootstrap 3 eventhough the question is tagged [bootstrap-4](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-4)